# Save a dynamically created button

Tags: .net, vb.net, button

[image]
When I click add, I will be able to click anywhere, and add button (Click Me) at run time.
How can I save the button so that next time I run the app, those 4 will appear there? Also, would want each of the button to have different events but that's not my priority as of now.
Can anyone give a way?

Answer (score 0):

If you were just after saving text or some specific properties of controls between sessions then the obvious thing to use would be application settings.  Saving dynamically created controls themselves and individual event handlers for those is a little beyond the basic use of application settings.

The only thing I could suggest (and I haven't tested this) is to try and find a way to dynamically change a basic script that creates the controls (and event handlers) store that script in an application setting and then run that script on form load next time you run the application.

You would need to be very specific about what you wanted to create, ensure that you save the necessary properties for the controls in question (location, size etc) and presumably build in a way to avoid running the script as well as running it.

This would involve doing a lot of error checking along the way.  I would think that you could just about do this but it would require an awful lot of work.  I would have to ask myself first why it was so important to be able to do this and if there is a better solution to the overall concept that I had in mind.

You should also bear in mind that application settings are user specific.  Fine if the same person is going to use your application, not so fine if different people are.

Answer (score 0):

you really cant save a button, but you can save the information that allows you to create a new button to appear in the same location.  One way might be Settings - just save the Size and Location of each.  Another way is serialization:

```
 Friend _ctrls As List(Of ControlSettings)

<Serializable>
 Public Class ControlSettings
    Public Property ctrlLocation As Point

    Public Property CtrlSize as Size

    ' likely other things:
    Public Property CameraID As Integer
    Public Property CtrlText As String
    ... etc
 End Class
```

To save settings, harvest all the relevant props from the form buttons:

```
 Dim cs As New ControlSettings

 With cs
     .ctrlLocation = thisButton.Location
     .CtrlSize = thisButton.Size
     ' etc
  End With
 _ctrls.Add(cs)
```

When you are done, `_ctrls` will have all the info for all the buttons.  Next, serialize it:

```
 Dim mUserFile As String = UsersFolder_Location_And_Name

 Dim fs As New FileStream(mUserFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

 Serializer.Serialize(fs, _ctrls)
 fs.Close()
 fs.Dispose()
```

Next time the app runs, you load the info in reverse order, and create new buttons from the values:

```
Dim Btn as New Button
btn.Location = _ctrls(n).ctrlLocation 
btn.Size = _ctrls(n).CtrlSize 
theForm.Controls.Add(btn)

' rehook the event handler(s)
AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will take time for me to study this first. Just stick around please? :) Also, where do I save this? I think I've seen some yesterday about saving it through an XML file? I aslo do have my access DB. What's better?

Comment: you can use an XML serializer if you want, that is more or less to save as binary to the file name you specify.  users cant tinker with binary files

Comment: I think I am gonna end up in this scenario, I was thinking if you could give me a link where I can learn application settings step by step, I thought this was the strings tab in `my.resources` but it seems like its different, so I think settings is a bit complicated than that. Also, I can't really understand those from MSDN. If you don't know such sites, its okay. Thanks!