# Add name in My.Settings

Tags: .net, vb.net, application-settings

How to add a new name in My.Settings?
So far, I've learned how to read and edit values in it, but how can I add another row/name at run-time?

Something like:

```
My.Settings.AddName.String("foo1")
My.Settings.Save()
My.Settings.foo1 = "fooNew"
```

I can't see such on the web.. Thanks
**EDIT:** *will be* used for the name,text and location of dynamically added buttons.
[SeeThisLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157932/save-a-dynamically-created-button)

Comment: Are they going to be like objects?  If so use a collection or a dictionary instead of discreet objects.

Comment: for button locations actually, check update..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `My.Settings` application settings are compiled into your assembly. The properties cannot be altered at runtime because of this. Expecting new settings to be available at runtime through the `My.Settings` property will not be possible. You would need to resort to more rudimentary techniques like those highlighted by [this MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bc0cd6cf-351d-4393-9111-596374189b87/vbnet-application-settings).

Comment: EDIT: updated to reflect the need for runtime editing of the properties.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say, MSDN said, user settings, can do read/write properties, and I just tried it. Its perfectly working, what I want now, is how to add another name at run-time/via code + user input. Something like that. Not the existing `Properties>Settings.Settings>Type in what you want`

Comment: You're absolutely right, the properties can be read/written but adding new properties at runtime is impossible given _when_ the `My.Settings` object defined (at runtime) How do you expect to reference a property that isn't defined by the type before compile time???

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it at runtime with whats built into my.settings namespace, however its entirely possible.  Id love to take credit for this but it has already been answered on stackoverflow.

As long as you know the file path and node name, you can build your own xml parser class to do whatever you want using this very simple example I couldn't write any more clearly:

[How to programatically add nodes at certain locations in xml config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270420/how-to-programatically-add-nodes-at-certain-locations-in-xml-config-file)